# Get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." even if I exclude null

Tags: c#

I have the following code using the datagridview which you can only select one whole row:
"Variable.addModArray[i]" is a string[];

```
class Variables
{
    public static string[] addModArray;
}

int i = 0;
while (i < dgv.SelectedRows.Count)
{
    if (dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value != null)
        Variables.addModArray[i] = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString(); //gets error
    i++;
}
```

When I run the code, I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error, but I already told the computer do the code if the value is not null! Did I do anything wrong?

Tell me if I need to add anything to this question.

Comment: Which line gives you the error? Is `dgv.SelectedRows` null? Also, you are iterating over the count of `SelectedRows` but using the index on `Cells`

Comment: Which line gives you this error?

Comment: What if `dvg.SelectedRows[0].Cells` is null? What if `dvg.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i]` is null? Why are you always using `dgv.SelectedRows[0]` instead of `dgv.SelectedRows[i]`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is or `Variables` is null. or `addModArray` is null

Comment: @Jehof Can you please answer my question please, because you solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could also be that `Variables` or `addModArray` are null.

Comment: Thank you! my `public static string[] addModArray;` should be `public static string[] addModArray = string[100];`

Answer (score 1):

First, for any given combination of `a.b.c`, checking that `a.b.c != null` doesn't mean that `a.b` can't be null, or that `a` can't be null.

As other commentators have pointed out, it also doesn't prevent other variables from being null.

Second, it's not clear why you're increment `i` for each selected row but not using anything but the first row.

You say you can only select one row, so why bother with a loop?

I would expect:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < dgv.SelectedRows.Count)
{
    if (dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value != null)
        Variables.addModArray[i] = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString(); //gets error
    i++;
}
```

to be:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < dgv.SelectedRows.Count)
{
    if (dgv.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
        Variables.addModArray[i] = dgv.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //gets error
    i++;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < dgv.SelectedCells.Count)
{
    if (dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value != null)
        Variables.addModArray[i] = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString(); //gets error
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Or Maybe `(i < dgv.SelectedRows.Cells.Count)` since there is only one row to be selected.

Comment: @AbZy Yeah I came to that possibility a little while ago. I'll put it in.

Comment: I'm not that much for WPF or WinForms or whatever this is. But if there's a `SelectedCells` property, shouldn't there be a `SelectedCells` indexer? So why bother with `SelectedRows[0]`?

Comment: The point is I want to store the info in the cells in the selected row to my array.

Comment: @DanielCheung I'm not sure if this matters, but are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: @DanielCheung Well I think my last code sample is closer to what you want, but not ideal if there's an indexer on `SelectedCells`, or `SelectedCells` can be enumerated (a la `foreach (var cell in dgv.SelectedCells`).

Comment: I've also tried If (dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i] != null && dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value != null) but still...

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
   //please try this
    int i = 0;
    if(dgv.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        while (i < dgv.Columns.Count)
        {
            Variables.addModArray[i] = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].FormattedValue; 
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: still, The problem is the computer said that the cell is null, but I already added the If statement.

Comment: Add Convert.ToString or FormattedValue

Comment: But I am sure I have something in the row

Comment: Formatted Value handles null value right you could remove your if logic

Comment: What if not all columns can be selected?